# Appendix Chapters typeset as Sections in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, tocloft

I am very new to LaTeX and still more in a trial and error phase than on a real understanding level.

My goal is to have all appendices - which are chapters and I would like to keep it that way - to appear in the TOC as sections, under a 'chapter' appendices.

Here is what I tried, using the tocloft package

```
\newpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\appendix

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{\cftsecindent}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\cftsecfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftsecleader}

\chapter{chapter title}
```

So my idea was to just tell LaTeX to write chapters to the TOC as though they were sections. My code has no effect whatsoever. Any ideas/solutions are very much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had the right idea, but you need to add your changes to the TOC itself rather than in the main document (and because of this you need to `\protect` some of the commands.) Note that this solution won't look very nice if your appendices have sections.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\newpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{\cftbeforesecskip}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{\cftsecindent}
\protect\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\cftsecfont}
\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapdotsep}{\cftsecdotsep}
}
\chapter{An Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. I don't fully grasp yet what is happening at some points in the code, and where what is set. `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{\cftbeforesecskip}` might be useful in this context, too. I forgot to put it in my question...

Comment: I added that to the example.  If your appendices don't themselves have sections it definitely leads to a pleasing layout for the TOC compared to the alternative.

Comment: What is the best way to have chapters also appear as sections in the bookmarks? I am using the `bookmark` package and experimented with `\bookmarksetup{level=section}` or `\pdfbookmark[2]{...` but the appendices would remain at the same bookmarklevel as _Appendices_

Comment: @D.Roepo Sorry, but I don't have an answer to your question. It looks like a good candidate for a new question.