# Appendix typeset like a chapter with proper headings

Tags: header-footer, appendix

I have searched for a solution but the closest I found was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25191/appendix-chapters-typeset-as-sections-in-toc), which doesn't quite solve my problem.

I'm running *TeXShop* 3.96 on a Mac typesetting a large book (`tufte-book`).  In the base document I include separate chapters as:

```
%\includeonly{PaPCh1} 
%\includeonly{PaPCh2} 
...
%\includeonly{PaPCh11} 
%\includeonly{PaPApp}
```

The last file is the Appendix, which I would like unnumbered yet typeset in the style of the other chapters.  At the beginning of (within) `PaPApp.tex` I include:

```
\chapter*{Appendix} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

This properly typesets the opening in the style of a chapter, adds the Appendix to the table of contents line properly, and leads to proper equation and figure numbering.

*HOWEVER*... the headers in the Appendix remain that of the previous chapter (Chapter 11).  I of course would like those headers to treat "Appendix" as if it were the "chapter," with Appendix sections listed.

I tried the obvious approach of replacing the above line in `PaPApp.tex` with:

```
\appendix \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

but this does not typeset the first page of the Appendix in the style of a chapter.

- How do I ensure the Appendix is typeset as if it were a chapter, yet prevent it from being considered part of previous chapter (i.e., have the headers be based on the Appendix... not the previous chapter)?

Comment: Please add a MWE with the internal structure of the book and the Appendix. It will help take the guesswork out of me and converge on a solution.

Comment: It seems that you are using a different setup for the headings. The default of the class for a two-side book is
`LE` > page + book title; `RO` > chapter title + page

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a  MWE of a `tufte` book.

The default of the class uses un-numbered chapters so we can use `titlesec`, loaded by the `tufte-book` document class to change the style.

Before the chapter `Appendix` we change the style, to compensate for the absent chapter number, adding the left mark and the entry to the TOC.

**The TOC**

[image: w]

**A chapter**

[image: x]

**The Appendix**

[image: y]

**The Appendix headers**

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    

\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\leftmark}}}%chapter title
    \fancyhead[RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\rightmark}}\quad\thepage}% section title
    }

\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}

\title{A Tufte-Style Book}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}

%% For  ! Argument of \MakeTextUppercase has an extra } error
\renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}#1}}
\renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}#1}}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\titleformat{\chapter}%
{\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{blue}}% format 
{\parbox{4ex}{\itshape\huge\color{blue}\thechapter\hfill}}% label
{0pt}% horizontal separation
{}% before the title
[]% after the title 


\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter    
\maketitle  
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Introduction}     % a no numbered chapter and no TOC entry

1. \kant[1-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
2. \kant[2-7]
\section{S1C1}
    3. \kant[3-9]
\section{S2C2}
    4. \kant[7-12]
\chapter{Two}
6. \kant[6-18]  


\titleformat{\chapter}%
{\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{blue}}% format
{}% 
{}% 
{\hspace*{4ex}}% to compensate the lack of chapter number
[\markboth{Appendix}{}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}]% after> mark left and add entry to TOC

\chapter*{Appendix} % a no numbered chapter and no TOC entry
\section{A1}
    11. \kant[11-20]
    \section{A2}    
    12. \kant[12-13]    
    \section{A3}
13. \kant[13-20]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Alas, your code does not enable the sections within the Appendix to appear in the headers (as they should).  A fixed header (with "Appendix") doesn't preserve the header structure of chapters.  Clear?